# Is there a way in R to combine the functions slice_max (dplyr) and fct_other(forcats)?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, forcats

I´m trying to combine the functions slice_max from dplyr and fct_other from forcats to get a top n slice of a dataframe, based in a numeric variable, but I don´t want to lose the non top n factors. I want those other factors to be designated as "Others" to summarise or count after that if I need it.

For example, with a dataframe similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(acron = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG"), value = c(6, 4, 1, 10, 3, 1, 1))
```

If I want the top 3  subjetcs by their "value", I can use the next code:

```
df %>% 
  slice_max(value, n = 3)
```

Getting the next result:

> acron value
> DD    10
> AA    6
> BB    4

But I would like to designate to dropped "acron"s the factor "Others" similar to the results obtained using the function fct_other from forcats. I´ve tried this code but it deosn´t work:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(acron = fct_other(acron, keep = slice_max(value, n = 3), other_level = "Others"))
```

Any suggestion to get something like this?:

> acron value
> DD     10
> AA     6
> BB     4
> Others 3
> Others 1
> Others 1
> Others 1

Or even like this:

> acron value
> DD     10
> AA     6
> BB     4
> Others 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be using `fct_lump_n()`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(acron = fct_lump_n(acron, n = 3, w = value))

  acron value
1    AA     6
2    BB     4
3 Other     1
4    DD    10
5 Other     3
6 Other     1
7 Other     1
```

Comment: Nice answer.  I hadn't seen `fct_lump` before so just had a look at the [docs](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_lump.html).  It seems that `fct_lump` is now considered "historical" and its more specific variations are preferred.  E.g. `fct_lump_min(acron, 4, value)`.

Comment: @andrew_reece I didn't notice that it was updated. Thank you for pointing this out, reworked the post accordingly :)

Comment: @andrew_reece I used `fct_lump_n()` which does not have a `min` argument, but you are right, it can be solved also using `fct_lump_min()` by specifying the `min` argument :)

Comment: @tmfmnk, thank you. That´s it. The key was the use of 'w' as a weighted parameter based on another numeric variable.

Comment: The @andrew_reece suggestion it´s also working, but with fct_lump_min you need to know the numeric value below what you want to declare other factors as "other", in that case 4. It will come handy in the future, sure.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use the approach with `slice_max`, it needs to extract the vector 'acron'.  Using `pull`, it can be extracted

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df %>% 
   mutate(acron = fct_other(acron, keep =  {.} %>% 
                                    slice_max(value, n = 3) %>% 
                                    pull(acron), other_level = "Others"))
#   acron value
#1     AA     6
#2     BB     4
#3 Others     1
#4     DD    10
#5 Others     3
#6 Others     1
#7 Others     1
```

---

Or other option is `order` and `head`
df %>%
mutate(acron = fct_other(acron, keep = head(acron[order(-value)], 3),
other_level = "Others")) %>%
arrange(desc(value))
#    acron value
#1     DD    10
#2     AA     6
#3     BB     4
#4 Others     3
#5 Others     1
#6 Others     1
#7 Others     1

---

Or do the `arrange` first and then use

```
df %>%
   arrange(desc(value)) %>%
   mutate(acron = fct_other(acron, keep = head(acron, 3), other_level = "Others"))
#   acron value
#1     DD    10
#2     AA     6
#3     BB     4
#4 Others     3
#5 Others     1
#6 Others     1
#7 Others     1
```

To get the summarised output, do a group by `sum`

```
df %>%
   arrange(desc(value)) %>%
   group_by(acron = fct_other(acron, keep = head(acron, 3), 
       other_level = "Others")) %>%
   summarise(value = sum(value))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  acron  value
#  <fct>  <dbl>
#1 AA         6
#2 BB         4
#3 DD        10
#4 Others     6
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. Your aproach is right, but it´s more simple the use of the suggested function fct_lump_n using the parameter 'w' as weight